# presenting new view controller. tabbed icons go away

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a project that is a tabbed application. I have a button on my home page that goes to the second tabbed page but when it loads it gets rid of the tabs at the bottom. 
How do I prevent this from happening? my code:

```
func manageButtonPressed() {
let NVC:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
self.presentViewController(NVC, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

Comment: Your presenting a view on top of the existing view, if you don't want that then you should either make a custom view off of the tab view or use a uinavigationclntroller and showViewController instead

Comment: can you please give the code to do this? I am very new to swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

`self.presentViewController(NVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

With:

`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

This is assuming that your home page button is at index 0 on the first tab button of Tab bar, while second VC is on second tab at index 1. You may change the index based on the position of your tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use showViewController method off of a uinavigationcontroller.

So in the main storyboard of the view where you call the presentViewController you need to add a UINavigationController.  Then you can call in the view

```
 self.navigationController.showViewController(NVC, sender: self)
```

Then it will add the view onto the top of the navigation stack and will be underneath the tab bar